# Pandas Sampling Every Time Condition is Met

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe, I want to get the indices of each row when the sum of the previous row's column value (or current row's column value) is equal to or greater than n, then the sum restarts back to zero. So for example, if our dataframe has values:

```
index   colB
1       10
2       20
3       5
4       5
5       15
6       5
7       7
8       3
```

and say n=10, then the indices I want are [1, 2, 4, 5, 7] since the previous rows (or current row) for ColB add up to 10.

So far, I can do a for-loop on this dataframe to get the indices I want, but when there are many rows, it is very slow. Therefore, I am seeking help on a faster method. Thanks!

Comment: What is causing it to reset? You say "sum of the previous rows" (plural), but presumably you just mean the previous row (singular)?

Comment: How can the first row (index = 1) meet the condition?  There are no previous rows to sum.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, when ColB adds up to n, then I get the index. Then the sum of ColB resets.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a clever way with some combination of `cumsum()` but this is a tough problem because the value needs to reset after the sum is greater than `n`. So it's kind of like a rolling sum with a window no greater than `n`.

I would probably use a custom function for this.

```
import pandas as pd

def go(s, n=10):
    r = []
    c = 0
    s = s.tolist()
    cv = 0
    for v in s:
        if v >= n:
            r.append(c)
            c += 1
        else:
            cv += v
            if cv >= n:
                r.append(c)
                c += 1
                cv = 0
            else:
                r.append(c)

    return r

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'colB': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 15, 5: 5, 6: 1, 7: 3, 8: 1, 9: 12}})

df['group'] = df.apply(go, args=(10,))

indices = df['group'].drop_duplicates().index
```

Note that I modified your example numbers a bit.

If `df` is this:

```
   colB
0    10
1    20
2     5
3     5
4    15
5     5
6     1
7     3
8     1
9    12
```

`indices` is:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end, I just wrote my function (which was similar to yours) in cython.